# I am trying to create a Login website by Connecting Database to Registration Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["registrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from Table1 where UserName=' " + TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, con);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if(temp==1)
            {
                Response.Write("user already exists");
            }
            con.Close();

        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["registrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            string insertQuery = "insert into Table1 (UserName,E-Mail,Password,Country) values(@uname,@email,@password,@country)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", TextBoxUN.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEMAIL.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPASS.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ucountry", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("manager.aspx");
            Response.Write("sucess");
            con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("error" + ex.ToString());
        }
```

the error:error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '-'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at loginpage.registration.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\raja\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\loginpage\loginpage\registration.aspx.cs:line 45 ClientConnectionId:28cc7d33-4de5-4267-94a6-a6dd6d59ef49 Error Number:102,State:1,Class:15

Comment: **Incorrect syntax near '-'.** - you have a column called `E-Mail`, so you need to reference it as `[E-Mail]`. Though a better solution would be to just call the column Email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column name `E-Mail` is confusing the query parser.  Non-letter characters in column/table/etc. names are generally a bad idea, so the *best* fix is to change that column name to something like `EMail`.

You *can* use these characters in your object names if you really want to, but doing so requires explicitly telling the query which parts are object names by wrapping them in `[]` characters:

```
insert into Table1 (UserName,[E-Mail],Password,Country) values(@uname,@email,@password,@country)
```

The `[]` is specific to SQL Server and varies by other database vendors.

There's really no reason why you can't/shouldn't get in the habit of identifying objects anyway:

```
INERT INTO [Table1] ([UserName], [E-Mail], [Password], [Country]) VALUES (@uname, @email, @password, @country)
```

As a matter of opinion there are those who would argue that it's easier to read a query this way.  At the very least it's easier for the query parser to read it in the event that there are "special characters" in the object names.